# 2.82 Liquid cache not reseting

Tags: cache

I've built an effector, domain, and inflow, baked it and it worked as it should. Then I added to the effector, cleared data, and rebaked, but the fluid acted as though there was no add-on to the effector. Tried clearing all the simulations, and re-adding them, and an number of other things, such as final bake, and replay bake, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I moved the extended effector a bit, rebaked and it works....

Comment: I go to the cache and remove all the files.  I shouldn't have to do this.